# "Contains" twice in a collection using lambda expression

Tags: lambda

Hy, I want to find an item from a collection which contains for e.g. "30 days" .
I want to search firstly "30" and then "days".
How should I make this using lambda expression? Can someone give me an example?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please share any code to show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
string search = "30 days";

var result = MyEnumerable.Where(x=>search.Split(' ').Contains(x.fieldToSearch))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var search = "30 days";

var lines = new []
{
    "I will meet you in 30 days.",
    "Payment terms are 7 days",
    "I like 30 as a number",
    "I am happy",
};

var results = 
    lines.Where(line =>search.Split(' ').All(word => line.Contains(word)));
```